# How to make the footer change its height based on scroll up or down

Tags: javascript, css

I have a footer which is hidden by default and I want the footer to appear when the user reached the bottom of the page and while scrolling either up and down the footer changes its height, but I don't really know how to do that. Is there some kind of `onmousewheel`-event which detects when the user scrolls up or down?

Any suggestions are welcome...

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kusfq0ta/)

Comment: I think this could help you.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926366/mousewheel-event-in-modern-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use **jQuery**, its easy to detect scroll position. For example:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
    var scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
    if ((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight === 0) {
        //bottom of the page
    }
});
```