# Cross-browser mousewheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, mousewheel

I attach events from different browsers (versions) and last version of Firefox consists 3/3 of them, last version of Chrome constits 2/3 of them. So, how to process just one of events instead of 3/3 or 2/3?

```
$(window).on('wheel mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', (e) => {

    console.log(e);

});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mousewheel event in modern browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926366/mousewheel-event-in-modern-browsers)

Comment: No, it's not. Example in answer to that question isn't good at all, because Firefox fires events twice, because it has and mousewheel and DOMMouseScroll.

Comment: Latest Firefox fires `DOMMouseScroll` and latest Chrome fires `mousewheel`, as you can check in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/fen1x/pen/oJwLvV?editors=1111)

Comment: Yes, i know it. But if you test my code in Firefox you will get 3 logs in your console, in Chrome you will get 2 logs. I want to make that just one event will be chosen and fired.

As i understand that i don't need to use new event wheel to just detect scroll and get from it direction? Are mousewheel and DOMMouseScroll enough?

Comment: To make your example work  in Chrome and Firefox - yes, you just need to remove `wheel`. But [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel) advices replacing every non-standart wheel event (like `DOMMouseScroll` and `mousewheel`) with `wheel` event. Check cross-browser example at the bottom of the MDN article.