# Javascript mousewheel vs scrolbar scroll event

Tags: javascript, events, scroll, mousewheel

Is there a (reliable) way to distinguish between scroll event initiated by mousewheel versus when user uses browser scrollbar or scrolls by touch? If I add this event I get true in both cases.

```
document.on('scroll', function(){

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could detect the mouse wheel: 
Answer equivalent: 
 - [Mousewheel event in modern browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926366/mousewheel-event-in-modern-browsers)
 - List item

```
window.addEventListener("wheel", event => console.info(event.deltaY));
```

Comment: But this doesnt help answer my question.