# How to make left to right scroll work the same as up to down in horizontal page layout using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I attempted to build a horizontal page layout - my first one. I built it to work with scrolling up and down.

See here:

```js
$(function() {
    var lastPos = 0;
    
     $(window).scroll(function() {
        var currPos = $(document).scrollLeft();
    
        if (lastPos < currPos) {
            console.log('scroll right');
        } 
        if (lastPos > currPos) 
        {
            console.log('scroll left');
        }
    
        lastPos = currPos;
    });
});
```

```css
.scroll_outer-wrapper {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vw;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100vh);
  transform-origin: top left;
  /* I have to comment these two lines in order for the left and right scroll to work
     HOWEVER, the up and down scroll won't work.

     If I uncommend these two lines, the up and down scroll will work as expected, but the left and right scroll won't work anymore.
  */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
.scroll_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 400vw;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
  transform-origin: top left;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}
.scroll_section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.scroll_section.one {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
.scroll_section.two {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
.scroll_section.three {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
.scroll_section.four {
  background: pink;
  color: black;
}

#scrollBtn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll_outer-wrapper">
    <div class="scroll_wrapper">
        <section class="scroll_section one"><h2>section 1</h2></section>
        <section class="scroll_section two"><h2>section 2</h2></section>
        <section class="scroll_section three"><h2>section 3</h2></section>
        <section class="scroll_section four"><h2>section 4</h2></section>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I didn't take into consideration, and it was a newbie mistake, was that I might have to also add the **feature of scrolling from left to right as well as being able to scroll from top to bottom**.

Right now I'm pretty advanced with the project and changing the whole structure would be really troublesome, so I come to you with my last hope to salvage this project structure while also implementing this feature...

> TLDR; How to make a left to right & top to bottom scroll behave the same way (horizontal scroll) ?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/aerra/0gm82aw1/54/) is my code example.

Comment: The question is not entirely clear. What does it mean - "the same as top-down"? Can you say what exactly you want ?!

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov Please notice the behaviour of the page [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aerra/0gm82aw1/54/) when you scroll from top to down with the mousewheel. The page scrolls horizontally. I want the same scroll behaviour when the user scrolls from left to right (this can be achieved either with the laptop touchpad or with the apple mouse). I cannot explain it any better than this.

Comment: Now understood the problem ))

Comment: do you need scrolling of an internal scrollbar or an external one?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I'm sorry, I'm not exactly sure what you mean. The div with the class `scroll_outer-wrapper` contains the sections I am interested in scrolling horizontally, if that's of any help? This `scroll_outer-wrapper` is essentially what's getting scrolled, not the `body`.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62591046. Look at the **UPDATE**