# Zoom page with mouse wheel, click and drag to pan

Tags: javascript, html, css, zooming, pan

How would I go about making a scroll-and-pan effect with the mouse wheel for the entire page? Basically like any 2D editor with the scroll to zoom, click and drag to pan but for the entire body.

I haven't been able to find anything online about it.

Comment: Are you asking us to suggest you random libraries from the internet, or will you code the solution yourself? this is not Reddit or WhatsApp. Asking for 3rd-party libraries suggestions is not allowed...

Comment: The mousewheel event is reserved for scrolling. if you will highjack it for zooming, you won't be able to scroll. Is that desirable?

Comment: yes i don't want to scroll.

Comment: I will code the solution myself i just don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Implementation I made based off of vsyncs answer:

```js
window.onload = init;

let root;
let content;
let zoom = 1.0;
let translateY = 0;
let translateX = 0;
let middleMouseDown = false;

function init(){
    content = document.getElementById("content");
    root = document.getElementById("root");

    root.addEventListener("wheel", (event)=>{
        zoom += event.wheelDelta / 1000;
        if(zoom > 2.0){zoom = 2.0}
        else if (zoom < 0.5) {zoom = 0.5}
        console.log(zoom);

        transform();
    })
    
    root.addEventListener("mousedown", (event)=>{
        event.preventDefault();
        middleMouseDown = (event.button == 1);
    })

    root.addEventListener("mouseup", (event)=>{
        if(event.button == 1){
            middleMouseDown = false;
        }
    })

    root.addEventListener("mousemove", (event)=>{
        // console.log(event);
        if(middleMouseDown){
            translateY += event.movementY;
            translateX += event.movementX;
            transform();
        }
    })
}

function transform(){
    content.style.transform = `scale(${zoom}, ${zoom}) translate(${translateX}px, ${translateY}px)`;
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0px;
}

#root{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#content{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root">
            <div id="content">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know where to start, you will very soon hit another wall, because knowing where to start is the easy part. Here is a rough guide:

1. Add event listener to the `wheel` event (learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51276012/104380))
2. Start with an initial (current) `zoom` value and calculate the delta from the wheel event and update your `zoom` value.
3. Use the `zoom` value to manipulate the scale of the page in some form. You can use CSS `transform: scale()` for that, on the `body` element.
4. Add event listener for the `mousemove` event (learn how](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event))
5. Act upon the detected mouse move, and calculate how much you need to pan the zoomed `body` element in order to reach any of the 4 edges, and not beyond.
   panning may be done via CSS [`transform: translate(x,y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate)